# Is it faster to truncate a list by making it equal to a slice, or by using del?

Tags: python, list, optimization, slice, micro-optimization

Suppose I have a `list` `TruncList` with some number of elements greater than `n`. If I want to remove `n` elements from the end of that list, is it faster to **redefine the list as a slice of itself** preserving the desired elements, as by `TruncList = TruncList[:-n]`, or to **delete the slice of unwanted elements** from the list, as by `del TruncList[-n:]`?

Does the answer change if I was removing the *first* `n` elements from `TruncList` instead, as in `TruncList = TruncList[n:]` versus `del TruncList[:n]`?

Besides speed, is one of these methods more Pythonic than the other?

I would imagine that the redefinition method might be slower, since it iterates through `TruncList` and then reassigns it, while `del` truncates the list in place, but I'm not sure if either of these are the case.

I would also suppose `del` is the better route, because it seems like the natural use of the function.

Comment: Why don't you try it? See the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module.

Comment: @mhawke That may be the best question of all. :v
I'll do that now.

Comment: @Augusta And then submit an answer to your question with your results so that future generations will learn :)

Comment: @halex I'll do just that!

Comment: Depends what you what to do with the list afterwards.  If you `pop()` each item then that will leave the list in-place with "empty" entries that can be reused.    In CPython it is more efficient to pop from the right.  Subsequent appends to the list will use the entries without a resize (if the same number of elements, or less).   Of course the performance effect will vary depending on the size of the list.  Deleting a slice on the left will mean a resize (realloc or equivalent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll depend entirely on *how many elements you delete*.

In CPython, the `list` type uses a dynamic overallocation strategy to avoid having to resize the underlying C array too often. There is an `array` to hold the elements, and it is kept slightly too large at all times.

Deletion then (using `del TruncList[-n:]`) **could** be a virtually free operation, provided `n` is sufficiently small. In fact, you can safely delete up to **half** the size of the over-allocated array, before a resize occurs. Resizing requires copying across all existing references to a new array.

Using a slice is *always* going to create new list object, requiring allocation of memory and copying across of the elements involved. This is slightly more work than re-allocation of data.

So, without measuring time performance (using `timeit`), I'd expect the `del` option to be faster than slicing; in the case of `n < len(TruncList) // 2` (less than half the length) in many cases you don't even incur a resize, and even if you did, slightly less work needs to be done as only the internal array has to be recreated.

When you remove items *from the front*, you'll always have to recreate the internal array. The differences won't be a stark then, but creating a slice is still going to result in allocation for an entirely new object.

Comment: I have a list that (for external reasons) has twice the elements I need (which are "packages" of 3). When I want to get rid of the duplicates using `def deldup(al): for i in reversed(range(len(al))): if i%6>2: del al[i]; return al`, it's almost instant and takes up no memory. when i do `def deldup(al): return [x for i,x in enumerate(al) if i%6>2]` it takes forever and crashes my computer because of the memory usage (even if I `del(al)`).... what am I doing wrong in the second approach?

Comment: @BUFU your list comprehension copies the second half (all 4th,5th and 6th elements), where the first version deletes those elements to only keep the first half. I have no idea how big your input is here but I would expect something else to be different apart from the implementation of `deldup()` shown here to have problems like you described, however. Sorry, this is not something I can help with in comments.

Comment: yeah, I've tried `i%6<3` as well, no difference there. But thanks anyways. I was just wondering if there was some obvious stupidity on my part that led to my demise. :D I'll just go with `del` then.

Answer (score 5):

So I tested it out myself using `timeit` with these samples:

```
  ## Make a list of 500 elements and then remove the first 80...
def slice_front():
    "Make the list equal to all but the first eighty elements."
    trunc = 80
    TruncList = range(500)
    TruncList = TruncList[trunc:]

def del_front():
    "Use del to remove the first eighty elements."
    trunc = 80
    TruncList = range(500)
    del TruncList[:trunc]


  ## Make a list of 500 elements and then remove the last 80...
def slice_end():
    "Make the list equal to all but the last eighty elements."
    trunc = 80
    TruncList = range(500)
    TruncList = TruncList[:-trunc]

def del_end():
    "Delete the last eighty elements from the list using del."
    trunc = 80
    TruncList = range(500)
    del TruncList[-trunc:]
```

...and got these results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_front, number = 66666)
1.3381525804258112
>>> timeit.timeit(del_front, number = 66666)
1.0384902281466895
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_end, number = 66666)
1.3457694381917094
>>> timeit.timeit(del_end, number = 66666)
1.026411701603827
```

It looks like `del` is faster, and by quite a broad margin.

---

**EDIT**

If I run the same samples but with `trunc = 2` instead, these are the results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_front, number = 66666)
1.3947686585537422
>>> timeit.timeit(del_front, number = 66666)
1.0224893312699308
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_end, number = 66666)
1.4089230444569498
>>> timeit.timeit(del_end, number = 66666)
1.042288032264116
```

`del` is still faster.

Here's a test where nearly all of the list elements are removed: `trunc = 80` and `TruncList = range(81)`...

```
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_front, number = 66666)
0.25171681555993247
>>> timeit.timeit(del_front, number = 66666)
0.2696609454136185
>>> timeit.timeit(slice_end, number = 66666)
0.2635454769274057
>>> timeit.timeit(del_end, number = 66666)
0.294670910710936
```

In this case, `del` is somewhat slower than the redefinition method.

Comment: You are removing far fewer than half the elements, so no (internal) resize takes place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought that the lengths involved might have something to do with it right after I posted the first set of numbers, so I ran a few more tests with different parameters. It's about as you say.

Comment: Timings would be improved if you could create the test lists up front; create N lists of equal size for N `timeit` tests and have each test truncate one of those objects. It'll illustrate better what the difference is between the two.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll revise the method to reflect that now, thanks!

Comment: It's actually proving kind of tricky to get outside values to work with `timeit`. :s I only picked up the thing a half hour ago so this could take a little doing...

Comment: You can use `from __main__ import ...` in the setup argument (the second argument to `timeit` to import names from the interactive interpreter, then use a string for the first argument to use those names. `from __main__ import slice_front as test, long_list_of_lists; testdata = iter(long_list_of_lists)` for example, and the first argument could be `test(next(testdata))` to pass in each element of `long_list_of_lists` to `slice_front` each iteration of the `timeit` run.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In that case, would `long_list_of_lists` contain a fresh list for each cycle `timeit` would expect to run? Which is, in the given set of tests, equivalent to `long_list_of_lists = [[range(500) * 66666]`? If so, that is a *very* long list of lists, indeed!

Comment: Yup, that's kind-of the point, as you are destroying the lists. Use a smaller `number` argument to limit the number of tests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would it also do to use `testdata = iter([range(500)] * cycles` and change `timeit.timeit(..)`'s `setup` to `"from __main__ import slice_front as test, testdata, .."`, or would it interfere with the timer since the iterator is making a new `range` each time instead of pulling it one from an extant `list`?

Comment: you can do that; the whole list is still created up front though. The list comprehension is executed *first* before calling `iter()`.

Comment: Good to know! I'll get this updated in a little bit. I have a version built according to your example that runs in only a small fraction of the time.